# how to use \digit in sed regex

Tags: sed

I've read sed info. In "3.3 Overview of Regular Expression Syntax".
There is a description:

```
\digit
    Matches the digit-th \(...\) parenthesized subexpression in the regular expression.
    This is called a back reference. Subexpressions are implicitly numbered by
    counting occurrences of \( left-to-right.
```

I don't know what it means. Who can give me a example?

Comment: see also: [Capture Groups](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/660/capture-groups#t=201608190817276898192)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure!

```
$ echo "23 45" | sed -r 's/^([0-9]*)/---\1---/'
---23--- 45
```

Graphically:

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]*)/---\1---/'
#          ^^^^^^^^    ^^
#          capture -----|
#                   print back
```

As you see, in a sed expression on the form `s/search/replace`, you can "capture" a pattern in the *search* block and then print it back in the *replace* block by using `\1`, `\2`, ... The number is sequential and corresponds to the 1st, 2nd, ... group that has been captured.

```
$ echo "23 45" | sed -r 's/^([0-9]*) (.)/YEAH \2---\1---/'
YEAH 4---23---5
```